# Truncate but NOT Round in R

Tags: r

Really basic, but Googling didn't yield an answer. Is there a way to *truncate* a numeric value without *rounding* it?

For example:

```
vars <- c(23.4567, 45.6795, 34.5670)
```

I want the output to simply lob off the last two significant figures, but not round the output. What I want is:

```
vars <- c(23.45, 45.67, 34.56)
```

But the most common ways of doing this end up rounding (round, of course, but also *signif*:

```
round(vars, 2)
```

> [1] 23.46 45.68 34.57

```
signif(vars, digits=4)
```

> [1] 23.46 45.68 34.57

Please point me in the right direction if this has already been addressed here, but couldn't find it specific to R...

Comment: If it is a printing issue `format(vars, nsmall=2)#[1] "23.45" "45.67" "34.56"`

Comment: Thanks akrun -- not a printing issue, since I want to group by the truncated vars

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try with `floor()`

```
vars <- floor(vars*100)/100
```

However, this solution assumes that all values are positive, as `floor()` rounds to the next lower integer. If there are negative numbers this approach could yield undesirable results:

```
> floor(-23.441*100)/100
#[1] -23.45
```

A more general solution therefore consists in using `trunc()`:

```
vars <- trunc(vars*100)/100
```

This will remove any digit after the first two decimals, and it also works for negative numbers:

```
> trunc(-23.441*100)/100
#[1] -23.44
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `floor()` function, with a little extra help.

```
floor(100*vars)/100
```